# Setting up a Dive only Floyd Rose bridge so it Floats

Tags: guitar, electric-guitar, bridge

I have an EVH Wolfgang Special Guitar which comes with a dive only floyd rose bridge.

My problem with this is that I like to be able to do tremolo sound with it when soloing.

I can only do this by setting it up so it's slightly floating but when I do this I'm having a big time making it stay in tune.

Is this because I have not setup the bridge properly or is this bridge really not meant to float at all?

Comment: EVH was a dive-only guy. He nailed a quarter under the bridge of Frankenstein just to keep the bridge up. I'd guess that the Wolfgangs were designed for that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its sounds like to me that you are trying to treat a dive only bridge like its floating by raising it abit... This will cause tuning problems as it wasn't designed for use like that, and the string tension will be wrong. 
You could continue like this and try but really its just not meant for that kind of tremolo action.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to properly be able to pull up on such a system, there would need to be a rout in the body for it to sit in, otherwise it's designed to be flush against the top and only able to dive downward.